# Mocking a method to verify a timer functionality in GoogleMock

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googlemock

I have a function that sets up a timer under the hood which I'd like to test with GMock without using any delays in a unit test.

I could use `EXPECT_CALL` to determine `TimerWrapper` is invoked `freq` times but how could I verify each run was spaced out at `interval` without using explicit delays?

```
// Wrapper around CreateTimer utility
void TimerWrapper(int freq, int interval, std::function<void()> callback)
{
  // run callback freq times spaced out at interval
  CreateTimer(freq, interval, callback);
}

TEST_F(TestTimer)
{
  // verify TimerWrapper runs X times every interval
  // so if interval = 1s, freq = 5, there should be 5 times the callback would be invoked in 5 seconds
  
}
```

Comment: First of all I don't think you need a timer you need something that will call your functions at a given time interval (the underlying timer is an implementation thing). So first make an interface (abstract baseclass) for such a class where you can do something like `call_every(const std::chrono::system_clock::duration& interval, std::function<void()>`)`. Then create an implementation with a delay (thread/condition_variable wait) and one for testing with an extra function "call_next" which will call the callback immediately. In your test you can then inject this second class and use it.

Comment: Possible to have a sample code? Also there isn't really a way around without using delays/threads within unit tests, yeah?

Comment: I try to avoid the situation where unit test have to start threads themselves (the code under test may do that).

Comment: @PepijnKramer I like your answer in terms of how to split prod and test, though I'm not sure this answers what the OP is asking. xyf if simply controlling the delay mechanism from within UTs is fine, Pepijn's answer is the way to go. However, if the aim is to measure actual delays I'm afraid you'll need to incorporate more complex tests, e.g. by profiling, tracing or doing fun stuff with library-injection to intercept call to system clock. It all can be done, but keep in mind that unit tests are probably not the level it should be done at.

Comment: I just started realizing that myself... Then again testing delays is a whole different story unit tests can run on virtual machines instead of real hardware, which makes it extra hard. This example is indeed geared toward reducing unit test time and still test all the functionality.

Comment: @PepijnKramer another level of indirection could suffice, e.g. wrapping all delays in one's own API to replace it on test level or to use LD_PRELOAD... Depends on what is to be measured really and how exact is that supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for splitting test and production code behavior for timed callbacks.
Live demo : https://onlinegdb.com/gm75fZefIZ

The reason I used a condition variable is that unlike std::this_thread::sleep, it allows you to break out of the loop immediately when a stop is requested, resulting in better shutdown behavior.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// the scheduling interface
class scheduler_itf
{
public:
    virtual void call_every(const std::chrono::steady_clock::duration interval, std::function<void()> fn) = 0;
    virtual ~scheduler_itf() = default;
protected:
    scheduler_itf() = default;
};

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// note a very simple implementation of a scheduler
// uses one thread per schedule and only one callback can be scheduled 
// a production version would be able to run multiple scheduled callbacks
// 

class scheduler_t final :
    public scheduler_itf
{
public:
    scheduler_t() :
        m_stop{ false }
    {
    }

    ~scheduler_t()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{ m_mtx };
        m_stop = true;
        m_cv.notify_all();

        // the background thread will stop
        // destructor of future will synchronize with thread actually having stopped
    }

    void call_every(const std::chrono::steady_clock::duration interval, std::function<void()> fn) override
    {
        m_future = std::async(std::launch::async, [=]
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{ m_mtx };
        
            // wait for interval or until m_running becomes false (which happens during destruction)
            while (!m_cv.wait_for(lock, interval, [&] { return m_stop; }))
            {
                fn();
            }
        });
    }

private:
    std::future<void> m_future;
    std::mutex m_mtx;
    std::condition_variable m_cv;
    bool m_stop;
};

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// scheduler version for unit tests.
// it is passive and will only run one step when asked for.

class test_sheduler_t :
    public scheduler_itf
{
public:
    void call_every(const std::chrono::steady_clock::duration interval, std::function<void()> fn) override
    {
        m_callback = fn;
    }

    void execute_next()
    {
        m_callback();
    }

private:
    std::function<void()> m_callback;
};

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// object under test
// use dependency injection for the scheduler
// so you can either have the production version of the scheduler or the version for unit testing

class my_object_t
{
public:
    // pass a reference to scheduler, since it will have a longer live cycle then my_object_t instances
    my_object_t(scheduler_itf& scheduler) :
        m_scheduler{ scheduler }
    {
        m_scheduler.call_every(500ms, [this] { callback(); });
    }

private:
    void callback()
    {
        std::cout << "." << std::flush;
    }

    scheduler_itf& m_scheduler;
};

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main()
{
    // start a scope to manage the lifetime of the scheduler and object 
    // this scope contains the production code
    {
        std::cout << "production code ouput : ";

        scheduler_t scheduler;

        // inject scheduler into object.
        my_object_t object{ scheduler };
        
        // let mainthread sleep
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(4s);

        // scheduler goes out of scope
        // which will call its destructor, which will gracefully stop the scheduling thread

        std::cout << "   done\n";
    }

    // this scope contains the code for unit testing.
    {
        std::cout << "test code ouput : ";

        test_sheduler_t test_scheduler;
        my_object_t object{ test_scheduler };

        // to simulate a time loop in the scheduler without delay just call execute_next
        test_scheduler.execute_next();
        test_scheduler.execute_next();
        test_scheduler.execute_next();
        std::cout << "   done\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note this is for educational purposes only, a real scheduler/executor would be more complex. But this should give you an idea how interfaces and dependency injection can really help you with unit testing.