# Missing capabilities for unit test

Tags: c++, linux, tdd

I've implemented a C++ Class that will execute something in a timed cycle using a thread. The thread is set to be scheduled with the SCHED_DEADLINE scheduler of the Linux kernel. To setup the Scheduler the process running this must have certain Linux capabilities.

My question is, how to test this?

I can of course make a unit test and create the threat, do some counting an exit the test after a time to validate the cycle counter but that only works if the unit test is allowed to apply the right scheduler. If not, the default scheduler applies and the timing of the cyclic loops will be immediate and therefore executes a different behaviour.

How would you test this scenario?

Some Code Example:

```
void thread_handler() {

  // setup SCHED_DEADLINE Parameters

  while (running) {
 
    // execute application logic

    sched_yield();

  }
}
```

Comment: Showing class skeleton my help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: Assuming you are using "unit test" in the TDD-style, a unit tests should test a **unit**, to ensure *basic correctness*.  I'd **mock** the other stuff.  For example, if I had to test something that has to occur in an hour, I'd mock the scheduler and trigger the "one hour later..." as having happened.  I wouldn't actually wait an hour.  Also, I'm a fan of [doctest](https://github.com/doctest/doctest) test framework.  I like it better than Catch2 (which is also good), and lighter weight than Google Test or Boost Test (which are also good).

Comment: Testing the scheduler itself can only be done by using it in tests. But to test the effects of a scheduler on the rest of your code you make an implementation of the scheduler that you can control from the outside so that it becomes timing independent. (Similar to my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75091187/mocking-a-method-to-verify-a-timer-functionality-in-gmock/75092372#75092372. ). So make sure your scheduler has an "interface" that you can inject into other code (either by static or dynamic polymorphism)

Comment: Do you want the test to cover concurrency or only correct execution without considering concurrency?

Comment: I've added some example code of the loop. The sched_yield() method will return immediately if the SCHED_DEADLINE settings are not applied due to missing capabilities. A possible solution would be to mock the sched_yield() method (by a sleep call for example or fake timers). I could then test the mocked class by mocking the system calls. What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There two separate units to test here. First the cyclic execution of code and second the strategy with the os interface. The first unit would look like this:

```
  class CyclicThread : public std::thread {

    public:

      CyclicThread(Strategy& strategy) : 
        std::thread(bind(&CyclicThread::worker, this)),
        strategy(strategy) { }

      add_task(std::function<void()> handler) {
         ...
      }

    private:

      Strategy& strategy;
      void worker() {

        while (running) {
          execute_handler()
          strategy.yield();
        }

      }
  }
```

This is fairly easy to test with a mock object of the strategy.

The Deadline scheduling strategy looks like this:

```
class DeadlineStrategy {

  public:

    void yield() {
      sched_yield();
    }

}
```

This class can also be tested fairly easy by mocking the sched_yield() system call.